# audioContext Oscillator stopped working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, audio

I have a problem with the code that worked perfectly in Chrome but nowadays I assume due to Chrome update it stopped working.

```
var audioContext = new(window.audioContext || window.webkitAudioContext);
var oscillator = audioContext.createOscillator();
oscillator.type = 0;
oscillator.connect(audioContext.destination);
oscillator.noteOn(0);
setTimeout(function () {
   oscillator.noteOff(0);
}, 5000 );
```

The error message is the following

```
The provided value '0' is not a valid enum value of interface OscillatorType.
Uncaught TypeError: oscillator.noteOn is not a function
```

I didn't find any clue why this stopped working. 
I appreciate you help.

Comment: Yes, you should use `oscillator.start(0)` and `oscillator.stop(0)` nowadays. Also, `new(window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext);` caps on AudioContext and `oscillator.type` should be `'sine'` `'square'` or `'sawtooth'`

Comment: @Kaiido add this as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Valid values for oscillator.type are 'sine', 'square', 'sawtooth', 'triangle'. Some browsers also implement 'custom'.

http://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#attributes-28