# How to invoke a function on a css class onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have the following code:

```
<title>Web Audio API</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="post red">
      <div class="inner">
        <h2 class="title">Oscillator</h2>
        <div class="post_info">
          <p class="date"><i class="fa fa-audio-description"></i> Placeholder</p>
          <p class="read_length"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 1 minute read</p>
          <input id="red" type="range" min="50" max="5000" step="1" value="90"/>



        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </a>

  <a href="#">
    <div class="post green">
      <div class="inner">
        <h2 class="title">Filter</h2>
        <div class="post_info">
          <p class="date"><i class="fa fa-audio-description"></i> Placeholder</p>
          <p class="read_length"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 1 minute read</p>
          <input id="green" type="range" min="50" max="5000" step="1" value="90"/>

          <input id="green" type="range" min="50" max="5000" step="1" value="90"/>



          <script>



        </script>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>

  <a href="#">
    <div class="post purple">
      <div class="inner">
        <h2 class="title">LFO</h2>
        <div class="post_info">
          <p class="date"><i class="fa fa-audio-description"></i> Placeholder</p>
          <p class="read_length"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 1 minute read</p>
           <input id="purple" type="range" min="50" max="5000" step="1" value="90"/>
            <input id="purple" type="range" min="50" max="5000" step="1" value="90"/>
             <input id="purple" type="range" min="50" max="5000" step="1" value="90"/>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>

  <a href="#">
    <div class="post lime_green">
      <div class="inner">
        <h2 class="title">VCO</h2>
        <div class="post_info">
          <p class="date"><i class="fa fa-audio-description"></i> Placeholder</p>
          <p class="read_length"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 1 minute read</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>

  <a href="#">
    <div class="post pink">
      <div class="inner">
        <h2 class="title">Placeholder</h2>
        <div class="post_info">
          <p class="date"><i class="fa fa-audio-description"></i> Placeholder</p>
          <p class="read_length"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 1 minute read</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>

  <a href="#">
    <div class="post orange">
      <div class="inner">
        <h2 class="title">Placeholder</h2>
        <div class="post_info">
          <p class="date"><i class="fa fa-audio-description"></i> Placeholder</p>
          <p class="read_length"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 1 minute read</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>

  <a href="#">
    <div class="post yellow">
      <div class="inner">
        <h2 class="title">Placeholder</h2>
        <div class="post_info">
          <p class="date"><i class="fa fa-audio-description"></i> Placeholder</p>
          <p class="read_length"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 1 minute read</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>

  <a href="#">
    <div class="post blue">
      <div class="inner">
        <h2 class="title">Placeholder</h2>
        <div class="post_info">
          <p class="date"><i class="fa fa-audio-description"></i> Placeholder</p>
          <p class="read_length"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 1 minute read</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>

</body>
```

//JS

```
          context = new AudioContext();
          var osc = document.getElementByClassName('post red');


          osc.onmousedown = function () {
          var oscPitch = document.getElementByClassName('post red').value;
          oscillator = context.createOscillator(),
          oscillator.type = 0;
          oscillator.frequency.value = oscPitch;
          oscillator.connect(context.destination);
          oscillator.start(osc);

        };

        osc.onmouseup = function () {
          oscillator.disconnect();
        };
```

My attempt is to run the js code on a css class click event. say : red

I wonder if anyone knew how to do that. Basically it's just going to play the oscillator sound. The rest of the code is not important. Thanks!

Comment: (1) It is `getElementsByClassName` (note the plural elements with an s). (2) It returns a nodelist, so need to iterate or just use the first one by index.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I have researched and it seems that the browser doesn't need an item in the node list to know that you're referring to say the parent CSS class element. The first one in the node. Am I wrong?

Comment: Read here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.click()` to determinate when the `red` class is clicked. Here's an example. In this case, when clicked it only shows an alert. You only have to change the alert with your audio function.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  $('.red').click(function(){
  if($(this).hasClass('post')){
    $(this).find('input').each(function(i){
        // equal to var oscPitch = document.getElementByClassName('post red').value;
        var oscPitch = $(this).val(); 
        alert(oscPitch);
    })
  }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title>Web Audio API</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="post red">
      <div class="inner">
        <h2 class="title">Oscillator</h2>
        <div class="post_info">
          <p class="date"><i class="fa fa-audio-description"></i> Placeholder</p>
          <p class="read_length"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 1 minute read</p>
          <input id="red" type="range" min="50" max="5000" step="1" value="90"/>



        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </a>

  <a href="#">
    <div class="post green">
      <div class="inner">
        <h2 class="title">Filter</h2>
        <div class="post_info">
          <p class="date"><i class="fa fa-audio-description"></i> Placeholder</p>
          <p class="read_length"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 1 minute read</p>
          <input id="green" type="range" min="50" max="5000" step="1" value="90"/>

          <input id="green" type="range" min="50" max="5000" step="1" value="90"/>



          <script>



        </script>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>

  <a href="#">
    <div class="post purple">
      <div class="inner">
        <h2 class="title">LFO</h2>
        <div class="post_info">
          <p class="date"><i class="fa fa-audio-description"></i> Placeholder</p>
          <p class="read_length"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 1 minute read</p>
           <input id="purple" type="range" min="50" max="5000" step="1" value="90"/>
            <input id="purple" type="range" min="50" max="5000" step="1" value="90"/>
             <input id="purple" type="range" min="50" max="5000" step="1" value="90"/>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>

  <a href="#">
    <div class="post lime_green">
      <div class="inner">
        <h2 class="title">VCO</h2>
        <div class="post_info">
          <p class="date"><i class="fa fa-audio-description"></i> Placeholder</p>
          <p class="read_length"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 1 minute read</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>

  <a href="#">
    <div class="post pink">
      <div class="inner">
        <h2 class="title">Placeholder</h2>
        <div class="post_info">
          <p class="date"><i class="fa fa-audio-description"></i> Placeholder</p>
          <p class="read_length"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 1 minute read</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>

  <a href="#">
    <div class="post orange">
      <div class="inner">
        <h2 class="title">Placeholder</h2>
        <div class="post_info">
          <p class="date"><i class="fa fa-audio-description"></i> Placeholder</p>
          <p class="read_length"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 1 minute read</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>

  <a href="#">
    <div class="post yellow">
      <div class="inner">
        <h2 class="title">Placeholder</h2>
        <div class="post_info">
          <p class="date"><i class="fa fa-audio-description"></i> Placeholder</p>
          <p class="read_length"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 1 minute read</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>

  <a href="#">
    <div class="post blue">
      <div class="inner">
        <h2 class="title">Placeholder</h2>
        <div class="post_info">
          <p class="date"><i class="fa fa-audio-description"></i> Placeholder</p>
          <p class="read_length"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 1 minute read</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>

</body>
```

Comment: Why don't use in the same selector both classes (red and post)? you can use like that `$('.post.red')` instead of `$('.red').click(function(){` and later `if($(this).hasClass('post')){`

Comment: I don't know if the OP wants to treat this two classes together. Maybe in some case he don't want to fire the event even the element has this two classes.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers you guys are awesome!

Comment: Consider up voting my answer if it helped you. @eshalit

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
document.getElementsByClassName('post red')
```

instead of

```
document.getElementByClassName('post red')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the event in Pure Javascript, you can do the following.

```
var osc = document.getElementsByClassName("post red")[0];
var oscPitch = osc.value;

osc.addEventListener("click",function(e){
    oscillator = context.createOscillator(),
    oscillator.type = 0;
    oscillator.frequency.value = oscPitch;
    oscillator.connect(context.destination);
    oscillator.start(osc);
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you only have ***one input having class*** `red` then your `osc` variable should be declared like this.

```
var osc = document.getElementsByClassName('post red')[0];
```

To do detect your start event in order to play the sound you should use `addEventListener`.

```
osc.addEventListener("click", function(){

});
```

To sum up.

```
      context = new AudioContext();
      var osc = document.getElementsByClassName('post red')[0];
      var oscPitch = osc.value;
      var oscillator = context.createOscillator();
      oscillator.type = 0;
      oscillator.frequency.value = oscPitch;
      osc.addEventListener("mousedown", function(){ // or any other event
      oscillator.connect(context.destination);
      oscillator.start(osc);
      });
      osc.addEventListener("mouseup", function(){ // or any other event
      oscillator.disconnect();
      });
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried the following and now I have a web audio based question: (maybe you'd know the answer to that one ? ) I am getting the following in the console: The provided value '0' is not a valid enum value of type OscillatorType. The project is visible at: https://github.com/Elemino/wave_album

Comment: @eshalit i think this answer covers you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32069376/audiocontext-oscillator-stopped-working